# Как поставить фоновое изображение по центру

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Верстаю сайт. В макете была такая секция: фоновое изображение и белый фон. Выставляю background:url(.....) center(т.к по умолчанию картинку почему то тянет левее.) Но когда ставлю center, картинка просто исчезает. Помогите пожалуйста как поставить такой фон.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без кода ничего непонятно, но, если вы про треугольник внизу - то это не background-image

Делаете блок, делаете ему :after и по центру ставите треугольник с отрицательной позицией вниз.

Как-то так:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen1 {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.screen1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid gray;
}

.screen2 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen1">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div class="screen2">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

```css
.block {
  width:  150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  background: url("https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b9/15/d9/b915d9e4c116db9b934aa0cc01d02241.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px 75px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```